# Fetching spreadsheet data as JSON with axios and Vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js, google-sheets, axios

I'm trying to fetch rows/data from google sheet as JSON.

```
<script>
const url =
  "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1NXF6G5npwcGeo2v_9tSDzieSHjxe4QtA-I9iPzHyvMk/1/public/values?alt=json";
const axios = require("axios").default;
export default {
  data: () => ({
    entries: [],
  }),
  mounted() {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      this.entries = response.data;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

The JSON tree(?) not sure what it's called. I'm really new to this. looks like

[image]

How do I call it on my vue app

```
<v-simple-table class="mt-5">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="column in entries" :key="column.EmployeeID">
      <td>{{ column.EmployeeID }}</td>
      <td>{{ column.EmployeeName }}</td>
      <td>{{ column.RaffleTickets }}</td>
      <td>{{ column.TotalPromoter }}</td>
      <td>{{ column.TotalAHTGoal }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</v-simple-table>
```

Not sure how close I am from the my desired result.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but I'm getting the following error:
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/{ID}/1/public/values?alt%3Djson&followup=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/{ID}/1/public/values?alt%3Djson&ltmpl=sheets' (redirected from 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/{ID}/1/public/values?alt=json') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Ideas?

Comment: I can access the json version of the document via the url already (published and created share link) and deleted all header params from the axios request, but any other information here does not help either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the response data structure you should do :

```
 this.entries = response.data.feed.entry;
```

then in template :

```
  <tr v-for="column in entries" :key="column.gsx$employeeid.$t">
      <td>{{ column.gsx$employeeid.$t}}</td>
      <td>{{ column.gsx$employeename.$t}}</td>
      <td>{{ column.gsx$raffletickets.$t}}</td>
      <td>{{ column.gsx$totalpromoter.$t }}</td>
      <td>{{ column.gsx$totalahtgoal.$t }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Okay. If you could indulge me for my naivete. How do I make a v-data-table out of it? I've added headers: [{ text: "Employee ID", value: "gsx$employeeid" }, etc... to the data field and went as far as to add <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="entries"> </v-data-table>. But the web shows like 100 rows of [object Object].

Comment: You're looking to something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62995627/8172857

Comment: ok, you missed to add `$t` `[{ text: "Employee ID", value: "gsx$employeeid.$t" },`